# why after adding new user , passwordless ssh does not work

Tags: linux, hadoop, ssh

I have created passwordless ssh for localhost. I test it and work fine.Now when I create a new user with following command

```
sudo useradd -d /home/testuser -m -g impadmin impadmin_test
```

then after if I tri

```
ssh localhost
```

then it asks for password. can anybody help me what may be the reason behind this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue arrise because when add a user in the same group then it decreases the permissions of .ssh folder and its child files, so after adding new user just increase the permission of .ssh folder by
**sudo chmod -R 700 .ssh**

Then **ssh localhost** will work fine